# Disposable of injected class in IoC container

Tags: c#, ioc-container

I have `Parent` class and a `Child` class,
The parent has do something with the child and then dispose it.

```
class Parent
{
    private IChild _child;

    Parent(IChild child) { this._child=child }

    DoAndDisposeChild()
    {
        //code
        //this._child.dispose();
    }
}
```

Using `autofac`, I'm resolving the `Parent` and calls the `DoAndDisposeChild` method with:

```
container.Resolve<Parent>().DoAndDisposeChild().
```

I've succeeded to acheive this by using the `Owend` feature of `autofac` with:

```
private Owned<IChild> _child;
```

And modify the `DoAndDisposeChild` to:

```
DoAndDisposeChild()
{
    //code
    this._child.Dispose();
}
```

The problem is that I'm coupling my code to `autofac`, I'm looking for ways to implement the disposal issue **without** using `autofac`?

Comment: In general you should _not_ dispose something that was injected. Do you have a very strong reason to not leave it to the container?

Comment: @ShaharShokrani If you know when to dispose it then why inject it at all? Wrap it in `using` block.

Comment: The IoC container is supposed to be managing the object's lifetime.  What I'm wondering is how the container is supposed to know that it has to `Dispose()` the object.

Comment: Generally, the only thing that should dispose of an object is the thing that created it. The class into which the disposable object is injected does not know if anything else has a reference to it and is not expecting it to be disposed. This is an overall best practice, not just a dependency-injection thing.

Comment: @nlawalker: OK.  Same question.  How do you tell your IoC container to dispose the object when it's done with it?

Comment: @RobertHarvey it depends on the container implementation. Some implementations detect when an object is disposable and dispose it when it goes out of scope.

Comment: [Here you go](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/disposal.html).  Problum solved, Major Tom.

Comment: Thank you all for commenting, @Robert how does the link of autofac doc answer my question? It is still coupled to autofac isn't it?

Comment: If your concern is that you may need to swap out Autofac for some other container, then create an interface for Autofac's methods and call the container through that interface.  Then, if you need to swap containers, just write an adapter for the new container that conforms to your interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To decouple business logic from Autofac need to register a *Child*-class as having [external ownership](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/disposal.html#disabling-disposal) on *Composition Root*-level. In this case, Autofac won't worry about disposing of *any* instance of *Child*:

```
builder
    .RegisterType<Child>()
    .As<IChild>
    .ExternallyOwned();
```

Pass to constructor *IChild*:

```
class Parent
{
    private IChild _child;

    public Parent(IChild child) { this._child=child }
    // ..
}
```

As an alternative way, the creation of Child-instances can be charged to separate services such as Factory or [something else](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns#Creational):

```
class Parent
{
    private IChild _child;

    public Parent(IChildFactory childFactory) { this._child = childFactory.CreateChild(); }    
}
```

Comment: smth isn't a word.

Comment: Hey @vladimir, `ExternallyOwned` is an autofac feature, I will still be couple into it, About the other option, still try to work it out

Comment: @ShaharShokrani, about first option - the main point is that just Composition Root (place where registered all dependencies) depends on some IoC-container (another words, Composition Root has references to IoC-specific modules that is inescapble if you use IoC-container), but Parent-module and other modules don't have dependencies on IoC-container.

Comment: hey again, I do not understand why do we even need the `Owned` feature? I can just make the `IChild` implement `IDisposable` and call the `this._child.Dispose()` without the `Dispose` of the `Owned`.

Comment: hey, if you mean *Owned<IChild>* - it not used in the suggested way. The 'clean' *IChild* is injected to the constructor: *public Parent(IChild child)* and IoC-container won't care about disposing of it, now it is your responsibility. IoC gives us - instance injection, lifetime management, etc but not disposing of it.